# Макрос VBA, поиск ячейки по значению и запись столбца в переменную

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макрос, работает как ВПР. Ищет данные из основного файле в файле доноре, затем в доноре копирует соответствующие данные из заданного столбца и вставляет в заданных столбец основного файла.
Проблема: в основном файле номер столбца куда вставлять найденное переодически меняется. Нужно, чтобы производился поиск ячейки с текстом "за день" и столбец этой ячейки принимался за столбец куда вставлять данные макроса. Искать в строке 11 (если это важно).
Макрос:

```html
Sub updateEO()
Dim aData(), aShop(), aRes()
Dim sPath As String, dDate As Date, bFlag As Boolean
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Const sFolder As String = "C:\Users\111\Desktop\"
Const lRwStart As Long = 12 ' начало диапазона'
    With ActiveSheet
        i = 115 ' завершение диапазона'
        If i < 5 Then Exit Sub
        aShop = .Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(i - lRwStart + 1, 1).Value
    End With

    ReDim aRes(1 To UBound(aShop), 1 To 1)
    dDate = Date

    Do
        sPath = sFolder & "Экономический отчет (" & Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ").xls"
        If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then bFlag = True: Exit Do  ' файл найден'
        dDate = dDate - 1 ' если не найден, уменьшаем дату для следующего имени файла'
    Loop Until dDate = Date - 5 ' просматриваем максимум 5 файлов (5 дат)'

    If bFlag = False Then MsgBox "Нет файла-донора", 64, "ОШИБКА": GoTo err_

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath) ' открыть книгу'
        With Worksheets(Format(dDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")) ' если есть сомнения в наличии листа, нужна доп. проверка'
            i = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
            aData = .Range("B1:K" & i).Value
        End With

        .Close
    End With

    For k = 1 To UBound(aShop)
        For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
            If aShop(k, 1) = aData(i, 1) Then aRes(k, 1) = aData(i, 10) ' записываем найденное'
        Next i
    Next k

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(lRwStart, 45).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, 45).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
err_:
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сохранения номера искомого столбца объявляем еще одну переменную:

```
Dim lClmn As Long
```

Но, чтобы не занимат память, можно использовать один из отработанных счетчиков (`i` или `k`).

Искать значение в строке  - или в цикле, или с помощью фукции листа `ПОИСКПОЗ`(`Match`). Второй вариант проще и понятнее. Последние строки кода:

```
     With ActiveSheet
        lClmn = Application.Match("за день", Range("A11:ZZ11"), 0)
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Value = dDate ' дата  файла'
        .Cells(lRwStart, lClmn).Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes ' выгрузка на лист'
    End With
err_:
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо, работает